# WebView is not working in ios using React Native

Tags: react-native

WebView is not working in ios using React Native, but it is working in android. How to solve this. Please give me suggestion.

Comment: Without any additional information your question will be difficult to solve. Do you have any error or build information?

Comment: Have you tried running ```pod install``` from the ```ios``` directory inside your project folder?